# UPDATE from SELECT but still return selected data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have read a bunch of ways that has gotten me this far.  But I can't get to the finish line.
I have a table of coupon codes.  I want to use one transaction to select the next available code, mark it as used and input the order number.  I can get the update and nested select to work, but I cannot figure out how to actually return the coupon code from the select.  It just returns 1 row updated.

Here's what I've got:

```
UPDATE `prcoupon` pr 
SET 
    `pr`.`status` = '1',
    `pr`.`invoicenumber` = '09990002'
WHERE
    `pr`.`couponCode` = (SELECT 
            `prcoupon`.`couponcode`
        FROM
            `prcoupon`
        WHERE
            `status` = 0
        LIMIT 1)
```

Sample data
[image]

What I need returned is: `couponCode: SL2T-03A0-JVCY-W2XMXG`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? How can you know which row is next is there any column that can represent?

Comment: Added data and what I'm expecting. Thank you.

Comment: could you provide **full** text sample data? We would want to help you but the edit question is still not clear,

Comment: How can you know which row is next is there any column that can represent that?

Comment: @D-Shih it actually doesn't matter which row is next.  They are random codes.  So I just need to find the first available couponCode where the status = 0.  Get that code and return it, and then mark it that it has been used and update the invoice number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use `UPDATE ... JOIN` with `ROW_Nunber` windwon function.

```
UPDATE prcoupon pr 
JOIN (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY couponCode) rn
  FROM prcoupon
  WHERE status = 0
) t2 ON pr.couponcode = t2.couponcode
SET pr.status = 1,
    pr.invoicenumber = '09990002'
WHERE rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71ed6e37f624b3fda764034bf0ef7741)